# Center image vertically in div using only css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center an image which is contained in a div with display set to table. In it, I wish to display an image, which should be positioned in the center, both vertically and horizontally. I have achieved the horizontal position using margin:auto and setting it as display: table-cell, but it doesn't center it vertically. Any help would be great

```css
.overlay { height: 50%; background: red;position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 50%;
width: 100%;
display: table;}
.swipe {height: 80px;
display: table-cell;
margin: auto;}
```

```html
<div style="height:300px">
<div class="overlay">
   <img class="swipe" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/255751-200.png" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend giving the `.overlay` `<div>` a **[flexbox layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** instead of a table. Then you can center the image by simply applying three rules to the parent:

```
.overlay {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Note that you'll no longer need `display: table-cell` or `margin: auto` on `.swipe`.

This can be seen in the following example:

```css
.overlay {
  height: 50%;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.swipe {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:300px">
  <div class="overlay">
    <img class="swipe" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/255751-200.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use padding at the top and bottom

```css
.overlay { background: red; position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
padding: 5% 0 5% 0;
width: 100%;
display: table;}
.swipe {height: 80px;
display: table-cell;
margin: auto;}
```

```html
<div style="height:300px">
<div class="overlay">
   <img class="swipe" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/255751-200.png" />
```